# How to Change prop + Double Tab Shortcut for Properties to a Single Tab?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

On my home computer, when I type `prop` and then press Tab twice, it automatically creates a `public TYPE Type {get; set;}` for me with `TYPE` highlighted. I can then type a `TYPE` like `int` and then press Tab twice to move to the `Type` section.

When I do this on my work computer, where I have a ReSharper Ultimate license, I only have to press Tab once. If I press it twice, it skips past `TYPE` and highlights `Type`. If I type `prop` then Tab once, then type `int` and press Tab once, it moves to the next section. Again at home, I would have to press Tab twice both times to get this behavior.

As you can imagine this can be annoying when switching between doing development at home and at work.

My best guess would be that there is some ReSharper Ultimate shortcut for something sounding like "autocomplete and move next", since Tab on my home computer just finishes the autocomplete, and then another Tab is required to move to the next section, whereas one Tab does both on my work computer. That being said, I can't for the life of me find this hotkey or shortcut in VS options or Resharper.

I suppose it's possible that it's not a Resharper shortcut either, but it's the only difference between the two VS setups I can think of.